# Google Chrome Omnibox truncating searches after "#" - I.E. "c# foo" becomes "c"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-search

I have recently been finding myself stymied trying to perform searches for c#-related things in Chrome. The problem is that the omnibox truncates the # and everything after it.

This means typing c# foo" in the omnibox in Chrome and hitting enter returns highly unhelpful search results for "c" Google.

Any tricks or extensions that would allow me to type "c# foo" into the omnibox and return results that are related to c# and foo? Am I the only person with this problem?

Comment: I used to have that problem with Google searches in IE, but it got better on it's own.  I don't use Chrome, but does wrapping `C#` in double quotes help?

Comment: It works for me on Windows using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m.  I get results for the whole cearch term, not truncated after #.

Comment: It works for me too, so which version are you using? Any special settings for searches through your Omnibox?

Comment: Do you have instant search on? Do you have any experimental flags in chrome://flags turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the thoughts and qeustions.

I'm also running 19.0.1084.52 m.
No special settings like flags turned on.
Instant search is off.

And it doesn't seem to be plug-ins b/c it does it in Incognito Mode. However your questions did lead me to start looking for the problem in other places.

And it turns out it's the router: It's a PFSense router running Squid Proxy with transparent proxy and Proxy Filter. When I had Squid temporarily disabled for my IP, c# searches started working! (Why this is, or how to fix it sounds like another question after some more research.)